# best pattern for calling enableProdMode in angular2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to determine what is the best way to invoke `enableProdMode()` in angular2 without having to comment out/in per environment. I know it needs to be called prior to the `bootstrap`, but I'd like to do this in a way that I can turn ON dev mode by using a URL parameter such as `?devmode` so that I can run in devmode for development and then in production I will see no `GET` parameter present and invoke `enableProdMode()`.

Problem is I can't use any angular2 code to pull out the URL parameters prior to bootstrapping ...

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to invoke `enableProdMode()` (either prior to bootstrap or other) so you aren't commenting out/in lines of code for testing and delivering code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization is platform-dependent anyway so

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('devmode') < 0) {
  enableProdMode();
}
```

doesn't hurt.

Comment: thanks! i'm going to provide an answer that has a bit more detail for what i did specifically .. but this was the root answer that led me to it.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing (based on Gunter's answer) was to define a 'Global' service that I could query to know if I was in devmode or not based on the href.

main.ts

```
let developmentMode: boolean = true;
if (window.location.href.indexOf('devmode') < 0) {
    // devmode not found in the URL ... we are in prod mode
    developmentMode = false;
    enableProdMode();
}

bootstrap(HomeComponent, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    // initialize our global class singleton and set development mode
    provide(Global, {
        useFactory: () => {
            let global: Global = new Global();
            if (developmentMode) {
                global.enableDevelopmentMode();
            }
            return global;
        }
    }),
    provide(Window, { useValue: window }),
    provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '/' })
]);
```

global.ts

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class Global {
    private devMode: boolean = false;

    constructor() { 
    }

    isDevelopmentMode() {
        return this.devMode;
    }

    enableDevelopmentMode() {
        this.devMode = true;
    }
}
```

My solution feels a bit backwards to me because I feel like I'm thinking in 'double negative' logic but it's only for the bootstrap and everyone internal to the app can simple call `Global.isDevelopmentMode()` if they care.

Answer (score 0):

Note: There is already a built in function to determine if production mode has been enabled or not:

```
import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core'

console.log('Development mode: ' + isDevMode());
```

Note: This must never be called before `enableProdMode()` is called.

Yes I realize this is not a direct answer but once you've determined where to enable it this can be useful.